# Why is the earth supposed to move thus far?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wandering-earth

Warning, spoilers ahead.

In the film [The Wandering Earth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7605074/), the earth is supposed to move to another solar system, because the sun is getting stronger and larger over a short period of time.

However, why is the earth not only moved a little more out to the outer planets, instead of actually tried to "wander" to another system?

Is there an in-universe explanation I missed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wandering_Earth : "In the future, the Sun has aged and is about to turn into a **red giant**" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_giant : "They have radii tens to hundreds of times larger than that of the Sun. [...] red giants are many times more luminous than the Sun because of their great size" Also note: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wandering_Earth#Differences_between_the_film_and_the_novel : "the sun would undergo a helium flash and devastate the Earth"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the first five minutes of the movie: in less than 100 years the Sun will engulf Earth, and in 300 years our solar system will no longer exist. Considering that we need a sun for warmth etc., Earth needs to be moved to another sun, i.e. out of our current solar system.

> The Sun is rapidly degenerating and expanding. At this rate, the Sun will engulf Earth
>   in 100 years. Within 300 years, the Solar System will no longer exist.